# Downloading image with Python using selenium, requests and Pillow won't work

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests

I'm following a tutorial to download images with python of google chrome. I'm in the first step of downloading one image but it's not downloading anything however it does print Success. Both when I give a path and also when I leave the path like " " this to download it within my IDE I get nothing.

this is the code:

```
import requests
from PIL import Image
from selenium import webdriver
import io

PATH = "/Users/flaviamadau/Desktop/SchoolPython/chromedriver"

wd = webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=PATH)

image_url = "https://target.scene7.com/is/image/Target/GUEST_34ac5146-0911-4c3f-ae9f-473d268ad847"
download_paths= "/Users/flaviamadau/Desktop/SchoolPython/fotos"

def download_image(download_path, url, file_name):
    try:
        image_content = requests.get(url).content
        image_file= io.BytesIO(image_content)
        image = Image.open(image_file)
        file_path = download_path + file_name

        with open(file_path, "wb") as f:
            image.save(f, "JPEG")

        print("Success")
    except Exception as e:
        print('Failed -', e)

download_image(download_paths, image_url, "test.jpg")
```

any help or feedback is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To download image, simply save the `.content` from `requests.get()` to a binary file. For example:

```py
import requests


url = "https://target.scene7.com/is/image/Target/GUEST_34ac5146-0911-4c3f-ae9f-473d268ad847"

with open("test.jpg", "wb") as f_out:
    f_out.write(requests.get(url).content)
```

Saves `test.jpg`:

```
andrej@andrej:~/$ ls -l test.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8008 june  6 14:20 test.jpg
```